# Ruby program not reading through all lines of a text file

Tags: ruby, text-manipulation

I have a text file with a layout that looks like this:

```
2014-10-12 21:30:49
Some text here...
2013-08-30 10:40:38
Some more text here...
```

What the program aims to do is read through the file and change the format of the dates so that it would look like this:

```
10/12/2014, 21:30:49
Some text here...
08/30/2013, 10:40:38
Some more text here...
```

The issue is that the program only fixes the first instance of the date and quits. It doesn't seem to matter how many lines come before the first date or what comes after the first date. It just fixes the first applicable case it finds and then terminates.

Here's the code:

```
require 'date'

INPUT_FILE = 'some_file.txt'
OLD_FILE   = 'some_file.old'
TEMP_FILE  = "some_file.#{ $$ }"

File.delete(OLD_FILE) if (File.exist?(OLD_FILE))

File.open(TEMP_FILE, 'w') do |fo|
  File.foreach(INPUT_FILE) do |li|
    li.chomp!
    if ( li[/^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \S+)/] )
      fo.puts DateTime.strptime($1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S')
    else
      fo.puts li
    end  
  end
  File.rename(INPUT_FILE, OLD_FILE)
end

File.rename(TEMP_FILE, INPUT_FILE) if (File.exist?(OLD_FILE))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you put a print statement inside of the foreach, do you see it happening more than once?

Comment: @alex_milhouse oddly enough as soon as I added that print statement the program worked...I'm not entirely sure what's going on here.

Comment: Happy day! Glad I could unwittingly solve the issue?